# Конвертировать строку ASCII шестнадцатеричного кода в массив byte [] и десятичное представление

Tags: c#, ascii, modbus

Имеется необходимость работы с протоколом MODBUS-ASCII. Входящее сообщение представляет собой hex сообщение в строковом формате.

имеется:

string messInput = ":F70436000E954D..." и т.д.

необходимо получить:

byte [] message 1 = {0xF7, 0x04, 0x36, 0x00, ... и т.д.}

А в некоторых случаях часть сообщения типа

string valHex = "...E954D..."

необходимо перевести в десятичное представление:

int valDec = 955725

Может есть какие библиотеки для такой конвертации, или подход? 
Не хочется изобретать велосипед.

Comment: [тыц](https://stackoverflow.com/a/311179/5045688)

Comment: и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27362463/5796587) еще, для перевода в десятичный вид